# subplots in plotly R produces name of trace twice in legend

Tags: r, plotly

The following code snippet:

```
 p1 <- plot_ly(df_w, x = ~TS, y = ~y1, mode = 'lines+markers', type = 'scatter', name='Y1') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~T, name='T')

  p2 <- plot_ly(df_w, x = ~TS, y = ~y2, mode = 'lines+markers', type = 'scatter', name='Y2') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~T, name='T')

  subplot(p1, p2)
```

produces the following timeseries plot:

[image]

The the trace T is used in both subplots. I wonder if it is possible to have T appear only once in the legend and have the same color in both subplots.

Comment: It turns out its is possible to add manual colors and disable the legend in all but the last trace:                                                                                
  add_trace(y = ~T, name='T', showlegend=FALSE, marker = list(color="green"), line = list(color = "green"))


  add_trace(y = ~T, name='T', marker = list(color="green"), line = list(color = "green"))

subplot(p1, p2)